# What's wrong with this Google Places (radar search) request?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to get a list of 200 gyms in Washington, D. C. within the radius of 50000 meters.

For this purpose, I issue following request to Google Places API (radar search):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&location=38.895111,-77.036667&radius=50000.000000&sensor=false&type=gym

I get an error message:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

What exactly is wrong with that request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change type=gym to types=gym, that worked for me